# Number of zero divisors in a finite nontrivial ring?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let A and B be finite non trivial rings, show that the ring $A \times B$ contains at least $|A| + |B| - 2$ many zero divisors. 
multiplication in this case is defined as: $(a,b)\times (c,d) = (a\times c, b\times d)$.

Here is what I have so far: we know that we only need to show that there is at least that many, and there always exits a $(0_A , b)$ for some $b \in B$.

From here though I get stuck. Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** If $A = \mathbb Z_3$ and $B = \mathbb Z_5$, then there are precisely $3 + 5 - 2 = 6$ zero divisors in $\mathbb Z_3 \times \mathbb Z_5$, namely:
$$
(0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 3), (0, 4), \\
(1, 0), (2, 0)
$$
Can you see why, and how to generalize?

Comment: I tried to look at every number that is not a prime factorization of n and m where a = Zn and b= Zm but I am not sure how to prove that/ how it relates to the -2 or if I am even on the right track...

Comment: Plus how would this work if we did not have a prime Z? I am still confused on this...

Comment: If we were to replace $\mathbb Z_5$ with $\mathbb Z_{35}$, then we would only get more zero divisors than required, since for example:
$$
(0, 5) \cdot (1, 7) = (0, 0)
$$

Comment: If you also add $(0,0)$ (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_divisor#Zero_as_a_zero_divisor) to the list then the OP can notice that there are at least $|A|+|B|-1$ zero-divisors.